# Cucumber IDE for feature writing with autocomplete?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, ide, cucumber, bdd

Is there any Eclipse plugin for writing [features for cucumber](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/feature-introduction) with autocomplete functionality?
I guess that would be good to find and reuse steps from other features. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The [cucumber-eclipse plugin](http://github.com/QuBiT/cucumber-eclipse-plugin) illustrates one possible approach.

> As Xtext seems not to be the perfect solution for this special case, it is more like a case study then a working plugin.

Based on **[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)**, it uses the [cucumber grammar](http://gist.github.com/39375) (as in [Gherkin](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/gherkin)), it uses XText features to produce a full-fledge editor.

[image]